# Can't find system settings in lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu

This feels like such a silly question.

I just installed lubuntu I can't find a button for system settings in the panel (LXPanel 0.8.2). When I click on the lubuntu icon, all I see is 'run' and 'log out', nothing else. There's also nothing on the desktop and I can't figure out how to launch system settings from the terminal either. Help me please!!

Comment: Ubuntu has a lot of forks, my experiences weren't the best with any of them using a different desktop. Lubuntu is one of them. The only exception was: linux mint.

Comment: Several repair methods are described [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=68992)

Comment: I found a very nice solution: install i3-wm